# How to include maven dependency stated on other project to my project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, parent-pom

So here is the structure of my project:

```
pom.xml
--myproject1/pom.xml
--myproject2/pom.xml
```

This is the dependency that I want to include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Right now I have this dependency stated on parent `pom.xml`. And `myproject2` has `myproject1` stated as its dependency.

Because of some reason, I want to move this dependency out of parent `pom.xml` and move it to `myproject1/pom.xml`. However, it seems that `myproject2` cannot access the `junit` dependency even though `myproject1` is listed as one of its dependencies.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

scope `test` is not transitive. That's all.

If you want junit in myproject2 and you want keep junit out of parent pom then you must declare that myproject2 depends on junit.

Comment: Thanks!

I also have
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

For this one, I do not specify the scope, but it is also used in test. Does that mean I have to put this in myproject2 as well?

Comment: If you don't specify scope, the `compile` is selected as default. `compile` is transitive, so slf4j is accessible in myproject2